# Django rename model. New django_content_type is created instead of renaming the old record

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

Setup:

Django 1.7 | Postgres 9.x

```
class Buildings(BaseModel):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=25)

class TestGeneric(models.Model):

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey()
```

Let's say I created a `TestGeneric` instance, associated it with a `Building` and saved it:

```
TestGeneric.objects.create(content_object=Building.objects.first())
```

Now I rename `Buildings` to `Building` and run `makemigrations`. I'm prompted `Did you rename the app.Buildings model to Building? [y/N]`

I choose yes. I then run `migrate` and get:

```
The following content types are stale and need to be deleted:

app | buildings

Any objects related to these content types by a foreign key will also
be deleted. Are you sure you want to delete these content types?
If you're unsure, answer 'no'.
```

Regardless of what I answer Django automatically will create a new row in `django_content_type` with `building` as the name and label. Is there any way to just rename the `ContentType` so that all of my TestGeneric rows aren't blown away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used this on a project; the caveat being that this works without issue if you create the migration before you've already tried to apply the automatically-created model rename migration.

You'll want to change the app name, the model names, and the previous migration to match your setup; in this example we changed the name of a model from `profile` to `member`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations
from django.conf import settings

sql = """UPDATE django_content_type
         SET name = 'member',
             model = 'member'
         WHERE name = 'profile' AND
               model = 'profile' AND
               app_label = 'open_humans';"""

reverse_sql = """UPDATE django_content_type
                 SET name = 'profile',
                     model = 'profile'
                 WHERE name = 'member' AND
                       model = 'member' AND
                       app_label = 'open_humans';"""


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('open_humans', '0004_auto_20150106_1828'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(sql, reverse_sql)
    ]
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you run `makemigrations`, then create this migration with the dependency of the freshly created migration, then `migrate` both?

Comment: Glad it helped! This seems like a workaround for a bug in Django migrations to me--I would be surprised if it wasn't already in the Django bugtracker but I couldn't find it the other day. I'll try to look again and report the bug if it's not there.

Answer (score 1):

I can share this migration operation written for this issue:

```py
from django.db import migrations
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType


class UpdateContentType(migrations.RunPython):
    '''Database migration operation to update a ContentType'''

    def _update_contenttype_func(self, old_app: str, old_model: str, new_app: str, new_model: str):
        def func(apps, schema_editor):
            ContentType.objects \
                .filter(app_label=old_app, model=old_model) \
                .update(app_label=new_app, model=new_model)
            ContentType.objects.clear_cache()
        return func

    def __init__(self, app: str, model: str, new_app: str = None, new_model: str = None):
        if new_app is None:
            new_app = app
        if new_model is None:
            new_model = model
        self.app = app
        self.model = model
        self.new_app = new_app
        self.new_model = new_model
        super().__init__(
            code=self._update_contenttype_func(
                old_app=app, old_model=model, new_app=new_app, new_model=new_model
            ),
            reverse_code=self._update_contenttype_func(
                old_app=new_app, old_model=new_model, new_app=app, new_model=model
            ),
        )

    def describe(self):
        return (f"Update ContentType {self.app}.{self.model}"
                f" to {self.new_app}.{self.new_model}")
```

Whenever a model is renamed, I edit the migration file and add an `UpdateContentType` operation too:

```py
from django.db import migrations
from apps.utils.migrations_util import UpdateContentType

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0010_previous_migration'),
        ('contenttypes', '0002_remove_content_type_name'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RenameModel(old_name='OldModel', new_name='NewModel'),
        UpdateContentType(app='myapp', model='oldmodel', new_model='newmodel'),
    ]
```